# 3D Geometry Contest Math Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math, 3d

The problem is as follows:

Six solid regular tetrahedra are placed on a flat surface so that their bases form a regular hexagon H with side length 1, and so that the vertices are not lying in the plane of H (the "Top" vertices) are themselves coplanar. A spherical ball of radius $r$ is placed so that its center is directly above the center of the hexagon. The sphere rests on the tetrahedra so that it is tangent to one edge from each tetrahedron. If the ball's center is coplanar with the top vertices of the tetrahedra, compute $r$.

I know that the height of the "top" vertices is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ but i'm not sure how to calculate the point where the sphere centered in the center of the hexagon at height $\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}$ touches the tetrahedrons edges (the edges have to face inward). How would I find this point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hum de hum de hum..........===..

[image]

singing doo wah diddy

[image]

Comment: Is it common knowledge that the side length from the center of the base of the tetrahedron to the corner is $\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}$? How can this be derived if not?

Comment: Your cavalier and somewhat nonsensical musings add something to this answer. Im not sure if I wish all of this site were like it, or none of it were.

Comment: What is the tune I should be humming while I read the solution ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=43vOAw2sAFU  which has some plot importance in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L.A._Story

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  The reason for short texts: if i just paste in an image, say, or paste in lines from computer output, then attempt to submit as an answer, the system does some nonsense about proving I am human (it has gotten less intrusive of late). So, although I meant this one as just the pictures, i put in short nonsense lines first. These days, i would probably edit out such lines after the submission succeeds. The Hum de Hum comes from a comic strip by Berke Breathed, long ago. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Breathed

Comment: I love your answer & I love the tune ... I am looking forward to next one$\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 0):

As far as Asimov's question, it can be restated in 2D as: For an equilateral triangle of side = 1, how can you prove that the distance from the centroid to any vertex is sqrt(1/3)?

Divide the triangle symmetrically by drawing one of its medians (from a vertex to the midpoint of opposite edge).  Euclid proved that the centroid (intersection of 3 medians) lies at the 2/3 distance along each median.  From trig. of 30-60-90 triangle of hypotenuse = 1, we know that the longer leg is sqrt(3/4).  So just take 2/3 of sqrt(3/4).